# Image popup is not working in angular application using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, angular, angular5

I am trying to display image on the body using jQuery in my angular application. jQuery script is not working in my angular application for popup. I am not able to find out where is the issue.So, How to resolve this issue?

app.component.ts:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    var container = $('<div id="container"></div>');
    container.show();
    setTimeout(function () {
      container.appendTo(document.body);
    }, 10000);

    $('.popupbox').show();
    $('.close').click(function () {
      $('.popupbox').hide();
      container.appendTo(document.body).remove();
      return false;
    });
    $('.close').click(function () {
      $('.popupbox').hide();
      container.appendTo(document.body).remove();
      return false;
    });
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jquery-modal-uvr9f4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It’s just not a good idea to mix jQuery with Angular..

Comment: @MikeOne: You have any other idea?

Comment: This can be fairly easily rewritten using Angular mechanisms..

Comment: @MikeOne: How can do it? Please edit my stackblitz